# UILabel text variable not updating properly - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

As an introductory to Swift programming i'm trying to make a small calculator app. I am getting a bug when trying to create the plus-minus button function. The purpose of the button is when clicked, if the value of the display text is `> 0` a minus symbol is added at the beginning of the string (i.e. `8 ---> -8`, and if the value of the display text is `< 0` the value of the display text is multiplied by minus 1 and the display text value is assigned as a string of the new number.

My issue is that when I click the minus button the first time it works as expected, however, when I click it the second time (`< 0`) the display text still keeps the minus symbol before the number. My code is:

```
@IBAction func pmButton(_ sender: Any) {

    if toFloat(value: display.text!) < 0 {
        display.text = NSNumber(value: (toFloat(value: display.text!) * -1)).stringValue
        print(display.text!)
    }

    if toFloat(value: display.text!) > 0 {
        display.text = "-" + display.text!
    }
}
```

The value of `print(display.text!)` gives the correct value (no minus symbol) but on the actual label the minus symbol persists. This is even the case when I add some erroneous value to the string i.e.

`display.text = NSNumber(value: (toFloat(value: display.text!) * -1)).stringValue + "abc"`

would result in (`-8 ---> -8abc`).

I also tried adding `print(display.text!)` before I reassign the value (on line 4) and it reverts back to the original minus value. So it seems like `display.text` gets assigned in the function but never properly updates outside of the function.

I'm sure it's something super simple but can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first `if` block you change the value of `display.text` so that the second `if` condition is met as well; just use `else if` to only run one of the blocks.